# Angular form data post request

Tags: angular, typescript

Hey I have a Angular project and I want to send data from a form to Elasticsearch by making a post request. However I implemented some components but it does not work. Can someone help me?
Currently it compiles without any error however wen I press the button nothing is happening.

That's my html file

```
<div>
  <input placeholder="Enter post" [(ngModel)]="posts.text"/>
  <button type="button" (click)="create_Post()">Post</button>
</div>
```

Then I have a posts class

```
export class Posts {
  text: string;
}
```

That's my post services class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {catchError, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {Posts} from './posts';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostCreateService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  createPost(posts: Posts[]) {
    return this.http.post(`http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9200/users/_doc`, posts).
    pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        return data;
      }), catchError( error => {
        return throwError( 'Something went wrong!' );
      })
    );
  }
}
```

And the last one is my post component class

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {PostCreateService} from './post-create.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-post',
  templateUrl: './post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post.component.css']
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: any = {};

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private createpost: PostCreateService) {}

  create_Post(){
    this.createpost.createPost(this.posts).subscribe((res)=>{
    });
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

EDIT: I changed it as the comments said and now I get a CORS error "from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy"

Comment: That map() in PostCreateService .createPost is not necessary. So no request is triggered?

Comment: Do you get any error in console? please check the developer tools, if there are any errors post it here.

Comment: Replace the `form` HTML tag by a `div` and the button type by `button` instead of submit. If you want to use a form with a submit, there are specific ways to do it.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve cors from develop mode you should start with proxy. This a part of angular.

example proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/rest/elastic/*": {
    "target": "http://elastic.host.path",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

and serve command

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```